# Add fixed values to dataset

Tags: sas, sas-macro

I have data structured as follows in Table 1:

```
ID Variable1 Variable2 
1      2         5
2      10        2
3      14        3
4      4         3
```

I need to add the following data to the above table for each row in Table 2:

```
Coef        Value
Variable1C  4.2 
Variable2C  5.6
```

The final result should be:

```
ID Variable1 Variable2 Variable1C Variable2C
1      2         5          4.2       5.6
2      10        2          4.2       5.6
3      14        3          4.2       5.6
4      4         3          4.2       5.6
```

How might I pursue this? So far, I've only be able to get one of data by transforming table 2 and then adding it, but this is not what I want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simple data step should do that.

```
data want ;
  set have ;
  Variable1C=4.2 ;
  Variable2=5.6;
run;
```

If you have the data in a table then transpose it and combine them.

```
proc transpose data=table2 out=wide ;
   id coef ;
   var value ;
run;
data want ;
   set table1;
   if _n_=1 then set wide ;
run;
```

Comment: True, but this is not dynamic. This would be a pain to implement for 100 variables. How might I implement this dynamically?

Comment: What part of it is not dynamic? What is your meaning of dynamic? Do you have the values in another data set? If so that is is also easy but you need to describe the structure of your datasets.

Comment: I clarified in the original post. Table 2 has the fixed values and their labels.

Comment: Will work if you have variable names for the variable instead of labels. But I think that PROC TRANSPOSE will try to convert labels into valid variable names as long as they are unique in the first 32 characters.